# Issue applying Bootstrap panels markup to WordPress widgets

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am **learning** WordPress theme development. And i am adding widgets in theme sidebar section. I am using **Bootstrap panel** to display widget content.

My codes are:

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'mytheme_widgets_init' );
function mytheme_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Main Sidebar', 'mytheme' ),
        'id' => 'sidebar_main',
        'description' => __( 'Sidebar main widget' ),
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="panel panel-primary widget_sidebar_main clearfix %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</div></div>',
        'before_title' => '<div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3></div><div class="panel-body">',
    ));
}
```

It is working fine when i add title and content in Widget using admin panel.

**But** when i do not enter title then it create an additional **< /div >**.
And this case is invalid HTML.

How to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`widget_title`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/widget_title) filter to check if there is or isn't the title, and add the markup accordingly:

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'mytheme_widgets_init' );
function mytheme_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Main Sidebar', 'mytheme' ),
        'id' => 'sidebar_main',
        'description' => __( 'Sidebar main widget' ),
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="panel panel-primary widget_sidebar_main clearfix %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</div></div>',
        'before_title' => '',
        'after_title' => '',
    ));
}

add_filter( 'widget_title', 'mytheme_widget_title_filter' );
function mytheme_widget_title_filter( $title ) {
    $title = $title ? 
        '<div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">'.$title.'</h3></div>' : '';
    $title .= '<div class="panel-body">';
    return $title;
}
```

---

**Update**

If you want to apply the previous filter function only to the Main Sidebar, add it before displaying the sidebar and remove it right after:

```
<?php
    add_filter( 'widget_title', 'mytheme_widget_title_filter');
    dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar_main' );
    remove_filter( 'widget_title', 'mytheme_widget_title_filter');
?>
```

Comment: I am also use other widget without panel so i think they will affect if i will add this filter >> register_sidebar( array(
   'name' => __( 'Top content', 'mytheme' ),
   'id' => 'left_top',
   'description' => __( 'Top content widget' ),
   'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="%2$s">',
   'after_widget' => '</aside>',
   'before_title' => '',
   'after_title' => '',
  ));